# XPath - getting value from complex XML file

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to get the value of "value" attribute of second bean's property with name "jdbcUrl". I tried multiple xpath combinations, but the only one that works for me is `(//@value)[4]` which is not optimal at all because if someone changes order of properties, I will get the wrong value. Is there more safer way to do it using xPath?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="xxx" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="afsafa" />
        <property name="user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ngsi" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="resources" mapping="/resources/**"/>



</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

> get the value of "value" attribute of second bean's property with name "jdbcUrl"

That translates directly to

```
/*/*:bean[2]/*:property[@name="jdbcUrl"]/@value
```

That's XPath 2.0 syntax; if you're still using XPath 1.0 for some reason, then you can't use `*:local`; instead, either bind a prefix to the namespace `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans`, or use `*[local-name()="local"]`

Comment: Since the question is tagged with Java, I’m guessing it has to be XPath 1.0, since [Java SE only supports 1.0](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).

Comment: @VGR - when I think Java and xpath, I think Saxon. Not too many good reasons to be stuck with 1.0.